# Riak solr indexing configuration

Tags: php, solr, riak

I want to index datas from riak using solr..

What all changes should do in schema.xml and dataconfig.xml ??

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any Solr [datasource](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/DataSource.html) implementation for Riak right now. You could either write one (and then use it via [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler)), or simply write a process (in any language/platform) that fetches data from Riak, processes it if needed, and [sends it to Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages).

There's nothing in particular that needs to be changed in the schema. You still have to design your Solr schema according to your search needs, independently of the data source.

You might also want to take a look at [Riak Search](http://wiki.basho.com/Riak-Search.html), which implements a full-text search engine on top of Riak and uses an HTTP interface very similar to Solr's.

Comment: Riak's implementation of Solr-compatible interface usually acts weird because while executing queries it applies sort _after_ slicing. Slicing can be done only in key order or search score order.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference with Riak 2.0 series with older versions. You can now use [default schema](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/search-schema/) or custom schema to define your own index. 
You should never interact directly with Solr while using Riak. Riak handles all Solr related operations such as indexing and sharding of your data. 
You should use one of the Riak client on your language. Please note that there is no jdbc library for Riak.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/basho/yokozuna/develop/priv/default_schema.xml

Comment: See this very informative thread and be ready to manage 1 second lag in your app logic. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/CZF-7_h6bhI

Answer (score -1):

This would depend on your RIAK config. What fields do you have?

Is there even a JDBC-driver for RIAK?